# Frequent database calculations

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a browser php game.

There will be resources like metal, wood, food etc. Players will be getting the resources all the time (gaining resources speed depending on buildings/mines/farms levels).

The number of resources is saved in database `resources` table.
Lets say now that someone will be getting 50 000 of metal hourly.
What is the best way to save these values to database or recalculate them?

It would be crazy to add these values to the `resources` table every second to keep it updated. How to do it best?

Comment: What's the simplest solution? If the resources cannot be accessed by anyone while the user is not actively playing, then there should be no need to do anything: just catch up when the user logs in. If the resources can be viewed / stolen, then you'll need a batching / daemon process to do this.

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why would you need to recalculate every second for something that happens hourly?  It's not really clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: @David Players get resources every few seconds, it would be like 50 000 per hour. Lets say I have 1000 of wood and 10 sec later I want to buy something that costs 1015 wood. I will need to calculate how much he has like all the time?

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford a stateful design, I have found that it is usually best to keep and maintain them in session, and aggregate the changes and write them out to the database at set intervals (of say 10 minutes), or when the session ends.

High rates of update can kill database performance:  this impact is multiplied when the table you're writing to has any significant indexing.   Different databases can support different transaction rates, and if you have more than a  couple users, once-per-second updates will just *kill* performance.

An alternative is to write out these updates to a local or temporary queue table, containing only an index on the autoincrement field, and to have a sweeper process blow through it periodically to add those updates to the eventual target table at low priority.   This keeps the update overhead lower, and reduces contention to the critical table, but it also means that your application logic will have to read the database value, and add the "pending" changes, before it receives a usable value.

A last alternative that is kind of the midpoint of the two above ones is to use a queue for storing pending database changes, but it would make it more difficult to calculate point-in-time values when there are unwritten changes still in the queue.